# How do I find a comment I made on someone's video?

Tags: youtube, comments

About a month ago I posted a comment on a YouTube video.

I would now like to find it so I can copy the text to use  for a comment on a different video.

Is there a way to find my comment without scrolling through millions of other people's comments?

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll down to the last comment (in order to load all comments) and then simply 
press <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`F`**</kbd> and type in your nickname/channel name.

If you got a better kind of mouse you can do so-called "pro-gamer move" and click the middle mouse button a.k.a the wheel and drag your mouse down by few centimeters - this will trigger automatic mass-scrolling.